# Run JavaScript Code after Base64 encryption

Tags: javascript, function, base64

I have encrypted my JavaScript Code with the base64 method like shown [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/base64-encoder-decoder-with-javascript.html). But when I run the encode function with document.ready, the JavaScript function doesn't do what it should.

How do I realize it, that the encrypted code will be decrypted and start to rund the function?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: That depends on your code. Also note that Base64 is not an *encryption*. Why are you doing this anyway?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your fast reply. I'm doing it, because I want to protect my JavaScript Code from other persons. I know, that there's no way to protect it against every person, but I want that it is protected against beginners. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: So you want to "protect" your code against people who probably don't know anything about JS anyway... honestly, just don't do it and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: Encrypting to a base64 string makes perfect sense for shareability or when you want to create a bookmarklet (code run from web addressbar `javascript:eval(atob('...'))`, but keep in mind that it gives no security whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `eval` on the decoded string.

Example using the code `alert("test");`:

```
eval(decode64('YWxlcnQlMjglMjJ0ZXN0JTIyJTI5JTNC'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uFxnz/

Note: Using the `eval` function is associated with unsafe and inefficient code, but in this case you have as much control over where the code is coming from as you can, so it's doing just what you want it to do.

Comment: @Qwerty: That's not a built in function. Use the code that the OP linked to.

Comment: right.. But it does do what built in functions `btoa()` and `atob()` right?

Comment: @Qwerty: Yes, but those aren't available in all browsers. IE didn't have them until version 10.

Answer (score 2):

## To "protect" your code...

..you can use the following simple procedure.

However, keep in mind that it gives no security whatsoever. That doesn't mean there is no use case though. Encrypting to a base64 string does make perfect sense for shareability or when you want to create, for example a bookmarklet (code run from web addressbar `javascript:eval(atob('...'))`.

---

Now, let's say this is your code:

## 1. The Code

```
// commentary, Yaaay!
var myObj = {
    foo : function() { alert("Baz!")} ,
    html : "<div id='myDIV'></div>", // it's ["'] proof
    bar : 123 
};
myObj.foo();
```

## 2. The base64 string

```
1. var base64Fun = btoa((function(){
2. // commentary, Yaaay!
3. var myObj = {
4.     foo : function() { alert("Baz!")} ,
5.     html : "<div id='myDIV'></div>", // it's ["'] proof
6.     bar : 123 
7. };
8. myObj.foo();
9. }).toString().slice(13,-2))
```

Notice, that I've only added lines `1` and `9`, the rest is your code, intact.

## 3. Run it

```
eval(atob(base64Fun));

eval(atob("Ly8gY29tbWVudGFyeQp2YXIgbXlPYmogPSB7Cglmb28gOiBmdW5jdGlvbigpIHsgYWxlcnQoIkJheiEiKX0gLAoJaHRtbCA6ICI8ZGl2IGlkPSdteURJVic+PC9kaXY+IiwKCWJhciA6IDEyMyAKfTsKbXlPYmouZm9vKCk7"));
```

## Compatibility

#### `btoa()` and `atob()` are not supported in all browsers, but..

1. use a polyfil and teach the browser these functions. [link](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#base64-windowatob-and-windowbtoa)
2. find another way

Answer (score 0):

You can't run your JS code through a base64 converter and expect it to function.

What you are looking for is a minifier. Like uglifyjs:

http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs