# How to use base64 encrypted javascript on a web site?

Tags: javascript, base64

How to use a base64 encrypted JavaScript file on a web site? I have a base64 encrypted JavaScript file.
How to read from `<script>`?

Comment: You'd have to load it via Ajax, decode it and `eval` it. Or you might be able to use a script tag with a data URL. But you cannot just load in a `script` tag with its actual URL because the browser doesn't decode the script.

Comment: Base64 is not **encrypted**

Comment: are you just trying to read the file or do other things as well?

Comment: @Broxzier: Only if you don't know when *not* to use it.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/15850727/218196.

Comment: Can I put encoded data and script in one file? Such as `eval(base64_decode('Encodeddata...'))` for including a javascript file. Also, without ajax loadings?

Comment: @john3825 yes you can put `eval(base64_decode('DATA'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need base64 decode function in javascript, like [this one](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_decode/). Then use this code:

using jQuery:

```
$.get('your_base64_encoded_file.js', function(file) {
   eval(base64_decode(file));
});
```

Comment: Can it be smaller? Can I just call on an encoded file with the script from `<script scr="file_name">` tag from a page?

Comment: @john3825 The only way is to use data url like `<script src="data:text/javascript;base64,YWxlcnQoImhlbGxvIik="></script>` but you will need to embed the content of the script in url

Comment: Does **"data uri scheme"** have a function to call a data file?

Comment: [Webmaster Tools: Javascript Encrypter tool](http://webtools.live2support.com/misc_javascript_encrypter.php) has a file similar to that to fit in one encoded file..

Comment: To @jcubic: Can I just put all in one js file to make it faster to load? Loading multiple js files may take long time, it is a good practice to put all js files together if possible.

Comment: @john3825 Do you want to encrypt/obfuscate the file or have base64 encoding? `Does "data uri scheme" have a function to call a data file?` don't understand. `Can I just put all in one js file to make it faster to load` yes you can but I don't know if it work if you first encode and then concatenate. but it will work if you first concatenate and then encode.

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = 'function hello() {'+
             '  alert("world")'+
             '}'+
             'hello();';
var encoded = btoa(script)
var decoded = atob(encoded);
eval(decoded);
```

You might wan to use a polyfill like:
https://github.com/davidchambers/Base64.js
for encoding/decoding on IE,

Comment: I want to use as a **separate file** from a web page. How to put encoded data and script together in a file to be read from a webpage?